# Scala tuple function composition

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tuples

Let's say we have a 3 functions with `Tuple3` result:

```
def foo(a: String, b: String, c: String): (String, String, String) = {
  (s"foo_$a", s"foo_$b", s"foo_$c")
}

def bar(a: String, b: String, c: String): (String, String, String) = {
  (s"bar_$a", s"bar_$b", s"bar_$c")
}

def buz(a: String, b: String, c: String): (String, String, String) = {
  (s"buz_$a", s"buz_$b", s"buz_$c")
}
```

And I can compose them like this:

```
val (a, b, c) = foo("1", "2", "3")
val (d, e, f) = bar(a, b, c)
val (g, h, i) = buz(d, e, f)
```

But I want something like this:

```
val (x, y, z) = foo(bar(buz("1", "2", "3")))
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
foo _ tupled(bar _ tupled buz("1", "2", "3"))
// res0: (String, String, String) = (foo_bar_buz_1,foo_bar_buz_2,foo_bar_buz_3)
```

First, use eta expansion (the `_`) to turn the method into a `Function`. Then you can call its `tupled()` method, which takes a tuple and turns it into the required arguments.

Answer (score 3):

For ease of typing, imagine that we have the following type alias defined:

```
type String3 = (String, String, String)
```

You can use `andThen` or `compose` as sheunis said, and you can turn a `Function3[String, String, String, String3]` into a `Function1[String3, String3]` using the `tupled` function. 
Then when combined with eta expansion you get this:

```
val buzBarFoo = (buz _ tupled) andThen (bar _ tupled) andThen (foo _ tupled)
```

or this:

```
val buzBarFoo = (foo _ tupled) compose (bar _ tupled) compose (buz _ tupled)
```

Which both have the aforementioned type of `Function1[String3, String3]`

You can then use the function like you used before:

```
val (x, y, z) = buzBarFoo("1", "2", "3")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(arg: (String, String, String)): (String, String, String) = {
  (s"foo_${arg._1}", s"foo_${arg._2}", s"foo_${arg._3}")
}

def bar(arg: (String, String, String)): (String, String, String) = {
  (s"bar_${arg._1}", s"bar_${arg._2}", s"bar_${arg._3}")
}

def buz(arg: (String, String, String)): (String, String, String) = {
  (s"buz_${arg._1}", s"buz_${arg._2}", s"buz_${arg._3}")
}

val (a, b, c) = foo("1", "2", "3")
val (d, e, f) = bar(a, b, c)
val (g, h, i) = buz(d, e, f)

val newFunc = foo _ andThen bar andThen buz
newFunc("1", "2", "3")
```

There are two functions, `andThen` and `compose` that do this. They are only defined on `Function1`, which you can create by passing tuples to your methods.